# Help with a smart contract.Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to make a simple smart contract where you can create a car. It creates a new contract that allows you to change the name of the car. I would like only the mechanics to change the name of the car and I would like to have the becMechanic() function in the CarFactory contract so you don't need to become a mechanic every time you are changing a name. So the problem is that I can't access the mapping mechanics in the Car contract and I don't know how to do it.

```
contract CarFactory {
Car[] deployedCars;
mapping(address=>bool) mechanics;

function createCar(string memory _name) public {
    Car newCar=new Car(_name);
    deployedCars.push(newCar);
    
}
function getDeployedCars() public view returns (Car[] memory) {
    return deployedCars;
}
function becMechanic() public {
    mechanics[msg.sender]=true;
}}





contract Car {

string carName;

constructor(string memory _name){
    carName =_name;
}

function changeName(string memory name) public {
    require(mechanics[msg.sender]==true);
    carName=name;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In **CarFactory** added function **getMechanic**
2. In **Car** construtor added parameter referring to **CarFactory** contract
3. In requiry operator used call of **getMechanic** function of parent **CarFactory** contract

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract CarFactory {

  Car[] deployedCars;

  mapping(address=>bool) mechanics ;

 function createCar(string memory _name) public {
    Car newCar=new Car(this, _name);
    deployedCars.push(newCar);   
 }

 function getDeployedCars() public view returns (Car[] memory) {
    return deployedCars;
 }

 function becMechanic() public {
    mechanics[msg.sender]=true;
 }

 function getMechanic(address  _user) public view returns(bool) {
    return(mechanics[_user]) ;
 }

}


contract Car {

 CarFactory  factory ;
     string  carName;

  constructor(CarFactory  _factory, string memory _name) public {

    factory = _factory ;
    carName = _name;
  }

  function changeName(string memory name) public {

    require(factory.getMechanic(msg.sender)==true);

                    carName=name;
  }

}
```

Comment: Ayo thanks so much dude.Really appreciate it